# How to make a list of dataframes all equal in length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a number of DataFrames that are inside a list like this:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({"t":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],"A":[34,12,78,84,26,84,26,34], "B":[54,87,35,25,82,35,25,82], "C":[56,78,0,14,13,0,14,13], "D":[0,23,72,56,14,72,56,14], "E":[78,12,31,0,34,31,0,34]})
Y = pd.DataFrame({"t":[1,2,3],"A":[45,24,65], "B":[45,87,65], "C":[98,52,32], "D":[0,23,1], "E":[24,12, 65]})
Z = pd.DataFrame({"t":[1,2,3,4,5],"A":[14,96,25,2,25], "B":[47,7,5,58,34], "C":[85,45,65,53,53], "D":[3,35,12,56,236], "E":[68,10,45,46,85]})

allFiles = [X, Y, Z]
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = file_
    df = df.sort('t')
    list_.append(df)
```

The list then looks like this:

[image]

How could I shorten the length of every data frame, to the length of the shortest one?

EDIT. Keeping in mind that I would like to keep the list with df's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) if in `DataFrames` are no `NaN` values:

```
df = pd.concat(allFiles, keys=list('ABC'), axis=1).dropna()
print (df)
    A                        B                                  C              \
    A   B   C   D   E  t     A     B     C     D     E    t     A     B     C   
0  34  54  56   0  78  1  45.0  45.0  98.0   0.0  24.0  1.0  14.0  47.0  85.0   
1  12  87  78  23  12  2  24.0  87.0  52.0  23.0  12.0  2.0  96.0   7.0  45.0   
2  78  35   0  72  31  3  65.0  65.0  32.0   1.0  65.0  3.0  25.0   5.0  65.0   


      D     E    t  
0   3.0  68.0  1.0  
1  35.0  10.0  2.0  
2  12.0  45.0  3.0
```

And then create new list by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `list comprehension`:

```
list_ = [g for i, g in df.groupby(level=0, axis=1, group_keys=False)]
print (list_)
[    A                   
    A   B   C   D   E  t
0  34  54  56   0  78  1
1  12  87  78  23  12  2
2  78  35   0  72  31  3,       B                             
      A     B     C     D     E    t
0  45.0  45.0  98.0   0.0  24.0  1.0
1  24.0  87.0  52.0  23.0  12.0  2.0
2  65.0  65.0  32.0   1.0  65.0  3.0,       C                             
      A     B     C     D     E    t
0  14.0  47.0  85.0   3.0  68.0  1.0
1  96.0   7.0  45.0  35.0  10.0  2.0
2  25.0   5.0  65.0  12.0  45.0  3.0]
```

But in output is `Multiindex`, so you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by first level created by [`get_value`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_value.html) and then removed by [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html):

```
df = pd.concat(allFiles, keys=list('ABC'), axis=1).dropna()
lvl = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
print (df)
    A   B   C   D   E  t     A     B     C     D     E    t     A     B     C  \
0  34  54  56   0  78  1  45.0  45.0  98.0   0.0  24.0  1.0  14.0  47.0  85.0   
1  12  87  78  23  12  2  24.0  87.0  52.0  23.0  12.0  2.0  96.0   7.0  45.0   
2  78  35   0  72  31  3  65.0  65.0  32.0   1.0  65.0  3.0  25.0   5.0  65.0   

      D     E    t  
0   3.0  68.0  1.0  
1  35.0  10.0  2.0  
2  12.0  45.0  3.0
```

```
list_ = [g for i, g in df.groupby(lvl, axis=1)]

print (list_)

[    A   B   C   D   E  t
0  34  54  56   0  78  1
1  12  87  78  23  12  2
2  78  35   0  72  31  3,       A     B     C     D     E    t
0  45.0  45.0  98.0   0.0  24.0  1.0
1  24.0  87.0  52.0  23.0  12.0  2.0
2  65.0  65.0  32.0   1.0  65.0  3.0,       A     B     C     D     E    t
0  14.0  47.0  85.0   3.0  68.0  1.0
1  96.0   7.0  45.0  35.0  10.0  2.0
2  25.0   5.0  65.0  12.0  45.0  3.0]

print (list_[0])
    A   B   C   D   E  t
0  34  54  56   0  78  1
1  12  87  78  23  12  2
2  78  35   0  72  31  3
```

Another simplier solution:

```
allFiles = [X, Y, Z]

min_len = np.min([len(df.index) for df in allFiles])
print (min_len)
3

print ([df.reindex(np.arange(min_len)) for df in allFiles])
[    A   B   C   D   E  t
0  34  54  56   0  78  1
1  12  87  78  23  12  2
2  78  35   0  72  31  3,     A   B   C   D   E  t
0  45  45  98   0  24  1
1  24  87  52  23  12  2
2  65  65  32   1  65  3,     A   B   C   D   E  t
0  14  47  85   3  68  1
1  96   7  45  35  10  2
2  25   5  65  12  45  3]
```

EDIT1: Solution if `t` is `index` with `unique` values.

Get shortest `index` and then use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) in `list comprehension`:

```
X = X.set_index('t')
Y = Y.set_index('t')
Z = Z.set_index('t')
allFiles = [X, Y, Z]

min_idx = min([df.index for df in allFiles], key=len)
print (min_idx)
Int64Index([1, 2, 3], dtype='int64', name='t')

print ([df.reindex(min_idx) for df in allFiles])
[    A   B   C   D   E
t                    
1  34  54  56   0  78
2  12  87  78  23  12
3  78  35   0  72  31,     A   B   C   D   E
t                    
1  45  45  98   0  24
2  24  87  52  23  12
3  65  65  32   1  65,     A   B   C   D   E
t                    
1  14  47  85   3  68
2  96   7  45  35  10
3  25   5  65  12  45]
```

Comment: Amaze. Will accept the answer when the timer runs out.

Comment: How can I generalize the "keys" argument to any varying number of datasets?

Comment: You can use `range` - `df = pd.concat(allFiles, keys=range(len(allFiles)), axis=1).dropna()`

Comment: I should have mentioned this but "t" is actually the index by which the data must be sorted. The data frames in the list at the end have to have all corresponding t's. When I apply the code on a big dataset it seems that my t's are all scrambled. Does this make sense? This is why I sorted each dataframe by t when importing it.

Comment: Is possible `reset_index()` of each dataframe? I add another solution, but both need monotonic not duplicated index (`0,1,2,3,4...`)